# Can't kill process with any kill command derivation

Tags: process, kill

There is the process named flask I can't kill either with
kill -9 PID  #(PID found from ps aux | grep flask)

or with
killall -9 flask

it always respawns with higher PID

Comment: it is not relevant since I do not use popen

Comment: Whatever you can't kill and keeps respawning on Unix or Linux was set up as a daemon process, i.e.: was launched by the Init process at system boot and is a **server** application.

You typically have scripts to enable and disable daemons, which depend on your Unix/Linux version and distribution.

As you did not specify what you are talking about, helping you further is difficult. 

In most distributions you have a /etc/init.d directory which contains init scripts. 

Normally their usage is something like **command_name start** , **command_name stop**, **command_name restart**.

Answer (score 0):

this command may be useful for you. But be careful, this command will kill all python processes.

```
pkill python3
```